# How to disable warnings from @typescript-eslint?

Tags: typescript, eslint

Below is my code:

```
interface DeleteRecipeFunctionContext {
  handleRecipeDelete: (id: string | number) => void;
}

const RecipeContext = createContext<DeleteRecipeFunctionContext>({
  handleRecipeDelete: (id) => null, // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
});
```

createContext requires me to pass in a default function, so I am passing in a (id)=>null as a dummy placeholder before I pass in the actual function. I receive the warning from @typescript-eslint stating:

```
'id' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Writing `// eslint-disable-warning/no-unused-vars` does not disable the warning, but `eslint-disable-warning` does. How should I turn off this warning without turning off all warnings? On the other hand, is my approach of using createContext correct (to enter a dummy function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To selectively disable a warning generated by a plugin rule, use the syntax

```
// eslint-disable-line <plugin>/<rule>
```

in your case:

```
  handleRecipeDelete: (id) => null, // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

I do not know if your approach to creating a context is correct, that is something that you will need to test in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling warnings should be a last resort option. Couple of alternatives here:

1. Discard the parameter:

   ```
   handleRecipeDelete: (_) => null
   ```
2. Omit the parameter:

   ```
   handleRecipeDelete: () => null
   ```
3. A more robust option is to make your context nullable.

   ```
   const RecipeContext = createContext<DeleteRecipeFunctionContext | undefined>();
   ```

   and do a null check when accessing your context, often done in a custom hook:

   ```
    function useRecipeContext() {
      const context = useContext(RecipeContext);
      if (!context) {
        throw new Error("Missing RecipeContext.Provider value");
      }
      return context;
    }
   ```

Comment: 1 returns the same error (_ is defined but never used).
For 2, I defined handleRecipeDelete to take in an id of type string or number, wouldn't removing the parameter violate the typescript rule?

Comment: 3 works with slight changes (have to pass in undefined as the default parameter)
But it seems like a lot of work just to fulfil the default requirement, is that the only way?

Comment: @Samson I think eslint rules accepts #1 but maybe not TS. #2 should be fine since the function respects the contract of accepting the param (eg. ignoring it) and returning nothing. Just like returning null vs undefined, but void doesn't care.

Comment: @Samson #3 is what I would suggest. It's do-it-once-and-forget so less work than managing default values each time the interface changes and the error is useful when you attempt to access context in a test and it's not defined.

Answer (score -1):

Above your function you can add `// @ts-ignore`

Comment: this did not work